# What is the difference between autopilot and autoflight?

Tags: flight-controls, flight-instruments

Can you please give me some explanations about autopilot and autoflight system?

Comment: Why did two people think it was a good idea to welcome a new user with a downvote, without explaining why they disliked a reasonable question. It may not have been written in the best form, but please not that not everybody here speak english as their first language.

Answer (score 6):

**Autoflight** is the general term describing all of the following:

- **Flight Director:** A guidance system for the pilot and autopilot with various modes. See [What is a "Flight Director"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/what-is-a-flight-director) for details.
- **Autopilot:** A system controlling the flight control surfaces to follow the flight director.
- **Autothrottle / Autothrust:** A system setting engine thrust automatically depending on the selected mode. See also [What is Auto-thrust?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35330/what-is-auto-thrust).

For example, the Boeing 737 NG FCOM describes it as follows (Vol. 2, Chapter 4 - Automatic Flight):

> The automatic flight system (AFS) consists of the autopilot flight director system
>   (AFDS) and the autothrottle (A/T). The flight management computer (FMC)
>   provides N1 limits and target N1 for the A/T and command airspeeds for the A/T
>   and AFDS.
>
> The AFDS and A/T are controlled using the AFDS mode control panel (MCP) and
>   the FMC. Normally, the AFDS and A/T are controlled automatically by the FMC
>   to fly an optimized lateral and vertical flight path through climb, cruise and
>   descent.
>
> AFS mode status is displayed on the flight mode annunciation on each pilot’s
>   primary display.

---

Related: [What is the relationship between "automatic flight control system AFCS", "autopilot", "flight director" and "flight management system FMS"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/what-is-the-relationship-between-automatic-flight-control-system-afcs-autopi)